# Integrate mailchimp with nuxt js app

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, nuxt.js

The [solution provided here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46818889/how-to-integrate-mailchimp-with-nuxt-js-app) doesn't work for me :/

I am getting a message when running npm run dev

> ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors11:21:24
>
> This dependency was not found:
>
> - mojo/signup-forms/Loader in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib?{"babelrc":false,"cacheDirectory":true,"presets":[["D://Code//frontend//node_modules//babel-preset-vue-app//dist//index.common.js",{"targets":{"ie":9,"uglify":true}}]]}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./layouts/default.vue
>
> To install it, you can run: npm install --save
>   mojo/signup-forms/Loader

When I try to install it I am getting

> $ npm install --save mojo/signup-forms/Loader npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
>   npm ERR! Could not install from "mojo\signup-forms\Loader" as it does
>   not contain a package.json file.

Not sure what else to do.

This is my complete default.vue

```
   <template>
      <div>
    <header-block></header-block>

    <nuxt/>

    <footer-block></footer-block>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import HeaderBlock from '~/components/Header.vue'
import FooterBlock from '~/components/Footer.vue'

require(['mojo/signup-forms/Loader'], function (L) {
  L.start({'baseUrl': 'mc.us9.list-manage.com', 'uuid': 'xxxx', 'lid': 'xxxx'})
})
export default {
  components: {HeaderBlock, FooterBlock}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing the following although I occasionally get error notifications on sentry with the message "require is not defined" on the "function showMailingPopUp" line.

If anyone can help with that please let me know :) At least I have a starting point.

app.html (root file)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html {{ HTML_ATTRS }}>
<head>
  {{ HEAD }}
</head>
<body {{ BODY_ATTRS }}>
{{ APP }}

<script src="//downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/embed.js"></script>
<script>
function showMailingPopUp(){require(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"],function(i){i.start({baseUrl:"xxxx",uuid:"xxxxx",lid:"xxxx"})})}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```